# How to connect to a FTP server from a Wi-Fi Hotspot that prevents direct FTP connections?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, network, ftp

I am using the wifi at a library where they prevent me to connect to FTP servers for some reason. I need to upload my work.

Is there any tool or trick to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have found one solution:

[net2ftp - a web based FTP client](http://www.net2ftp.com/index.php)

Usual warnings concerning (non-)confidentiality of data etc. apply.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by connecting directly via Internet Explorer.
 You just have to tap in the url : ftp://ftp.yourwebsite.com / Then enter your password and that's it. 
But it can only be a temporary solution because I don't think it's really safe to do it that way ...

Comment: This still results in the browser accessing the FTP port on the server (which is blocked).